# If $\mathcal{L}(X_n)=\mathcal{L}(Y_n)$ and $X_n \to X$ in probability then does there exists a Y such that $Y_n \to Y$

Tags: probability-theory

If $\mathcal{L}(X_n)=\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \forall n$ and $X_n \to X$ in probability then does there exists a Y such that $Y_n \to Y$ in probability Is this necessarily true?

Case I:  $X_n$ and $Y_n$ live on the same probability space

Case 2:$X_n$ and $Y_n$ live on different  probability spaces

I have no clue on how could I show this. Any ideas?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{L}(X)=\mathcal{L}(Y)$ a notation for having equal distribution?

Comment: @drhab yes it has the same distribution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's work on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathsf P)$ where $\Omega=\{0,1\}$, $\mathcal A=\wp(\Omega)$ and $\mathsf P$ is determined by $\mathsf P(\{0\})=\mathsf P(\{1\})=\frac12$.

Now define $Y_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by stating that $Y_n(\omega)=\omega$ if $n$ is even and $Y_n(\omega)=1-\omega$ if $n$ is odd.

Further define $X,X_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by stating that $X_n(\omega)=\omega=X(\omega)$ for every $n$.

Then $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have equal distributions and $X_n\to X$ in probability.

But $Y_n$ is not converging in probability to any random variable $Y$.